# When can a green card holder apply for a US passport?

Tags: usa, passports, us-residents

I have been living in the US since July 2013, and have a green card. When can I apply for a US passport?

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, you don't "apply for a passport" just like that. You apply for naturalisation, i.e. US citizenship. If it's granted, then you can apply for a US passport.

As a green card holder, you don't *need* to apply for US citizenship if you don't want to. However, you do need to be a green card holder for 5 years (or 3 years if married to a US citizen) to apply for citizenship

Comment: Huh, I thought it was longer than that.